# Is there a way to test an SQLAlchemy Connection?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to write a pandas DataFrame to a MySQL database. Early on in my code I create an SQLAlchemy engine:

```
engine = create_my_sqlalchemy_connection()
```

I execute some queries, do some calculations, and then try to use that same engine to write to the database a little later:

```
df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Sometimes this works, and sometimes the connection is lost by the time the code is ready to write to the DB, and there is an error.

I could do a try, except and create a new connection if needed:

```
try:
    df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
except:
    engine = create_my_sqlalchemy_connection()
    df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

However, I thought I'd reach out and see if anyone knows of a better way (e.g. if there is some SQLAlchemy method that I am unaware of for testing to see if the connection still exists).

Comment: Do you have an idea what "a little later" is? Seconds, minutes, hours? I never had problems with code running for a couple of minutes so far, but I guess it could be different for longer intervalls

Comment: if df is very large, you could loop over df_chunks and call to_sql() on them perhaps?

Comment: ik this is kind of an old thread, but using a similar methodology was able to resolve the 'connection' issue in sqlalchemy using a commit function. not sure how to add that with pandas, but it is an issue i run into intermittently (maybe a versioning) and could be resolved by adding auto-commit to the engine initiation.

Answer (score 12):

You can have SQLAlchemy check for the liveness of the connection with the parameter `pool_pre_ping`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.pool_pre_ping

> if True will enable the connection pool “pre-ping” feature that tests connections for liveness upon each checkout.

Simply enable it by using when you create your engine.

Answer (score 6):

The below code snippet perfectly worked for me.

```
from sqlalchemy import text

# check if the connection is successfully established or not
with app.app_context():
    try:
        # db.session.execute('SELECT 1')
        db.session.execute(text('SELECT 1'))
        print('\n\n----------- Connection successful !')
    except Exception as e:
        print('\n\n----------- Connection failed ! ERROR : ', e)
```

This is the complete code.

```
import os, sys, click, urllib
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import text

# Make sure to replace below data with your DB values
DATABASE_HOST = "10.10.10.110"
DATABASE_NAME = "dbtest"
DATABASE_USERNAME = "admin" 
DATABASE_PASSWORD = "admin@123"

app = Flask(__name__)

# to elimate the error, if the password contains special characters like '@' 
DATABASE_PASSWORD_UPDATED = urllib.parse.quote_plus(DATABASE_PASSWORD)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pymssql://'+DATABASE_USERNAME+':'+DATABASE_PASSWORD_UPDATED+'@'+DATABASE_HOST+'/'+DATABASE_NAME
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# check if the connection is successfully established or not
with app.app_context():
    try:
        # db.session.execute('SELECT 1')
        db.session.execute(text('SELECT 1'))
        print('\n\n----------- Connection successful !')
    except Exception as e:
        print('\n\n----------- Connection failed ! ERROR : ', e)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Does any part of this question indicate that the OP is using Flask?

Answer (score 4):

If you have problems with time outs when writing a Pandas Dataframe to a SQL server your Dataframe is probably quite large or there are many constraints that the database has to check when you insert.
To get around this you need to set the chunksize argument in the Pandas command:
`DataFrame.to_sql(name, con, schema=None, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)`

> **chunksize** : int, optional
>   Rows will be written in batches of this size at a time. By default, all rows will be written at once.

I don't know how many rows you have but 10000 is probably a fine value. The problem with this is that if your write fails now you will have inserted some rows but not all =( and you won't know which.

Comment: Oops, didn't address the constraints issue. For each constraint you have on the data the less likely it is to become anomalous but you pay for that by having to check for anomalies when inserting. Indexes also come with a cost at insertion time (but hopefully a benefit at query time).

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful to you since it seems like your connection is timing out. This is for anyone like me who found it useful.

From the SQLAlchemy documentation when working with MySQL:

> MySQL features an automatic connection close behavior, for connections that have been idle for a fixed period of time, defaulting to eight hours. To circumvent having this issue, use the create_engine.pool_recycle option which ensures that a connection will be discarded and replaced with a new one if it has been present in the pool for a fixed number of seconds:
>
> `engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://...', pool_recycle=3600)`

Answer (score 1):

It is really simple if you read the following document of link. You can check the connection status and recorver it before the df.to_sql statement:

`if conn.closed: conn = engine.connect()`

As you see, conn is a Connection instance. There is no .closed attribute for engine.
[sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.closed](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.closed)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937), even if this link may answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I test this '**connection_str**' for docker container.

```
import sqlalchemy
```

You can test if you know table names, I always use this method.

```
connection_str = f'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_str)
engine.connect()

metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=engine)
metadata.reflect(only=['test_table'])

print(metadata.tables)
```

Correct Output >> Should be if connection is OK and table name is correct:

```
FacadeDict({'test_table': Table('test_table', MetaData(bind=Engine(mysql+pymysql://root:***@localhost:3306/test_db)), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<test_table>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('DATAORA', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('SPORT', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('PARTITA', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('NAZIONE', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('SCOMMESSA', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('RATING', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('BOOKMAKER', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('QUOTA1', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('EXCHANGE', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('QUOTA2', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), Column('LIQUIDITA', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<test_table>), schema=None)})
```

Wrong Output >> If anything wrong (changed table name: test_table -> test_tables:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine(mysql+pymysql://root:***@localhost:3306/test_db): (test_tables)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's worth trying the [Connection.closed](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.closed) property.

```
if engine.closed:
    engine = create_my_sqlalchemy_connection()
    df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
else:
    df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: <class 'AttributeError'> 'Engine' object has no attribute 'closed'